# Set Environment Variable for Ranger File Manager

Tags: vim, environment-variables, ranger

I've recently stumbled across ranger file manager and immediately took a liking to it but I'm having a problem.

How is it possible to change environment variables for ranger? I want my default editor (e.g. pressing E) to be vim but setting: export EDITOR=vim in `.bashrc` doesn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger#File_association

Comment: Are you really using bash? As I use zsh, I had to set `export EDITOR=vim` im .zshrc and everything works fine

Answer (score 5):

I use `ranger` too, and `vim`.

Try `env EDITOR=vim ranger` then try out E option to open an editor for the file. If it worked, then the changes are not working for you for either of the two reasons.

1. You forgot to source `.bashrc` after editing it with `export EDITOR=vim` change.
2. You might be using another shell

For scenario one, just do a `source ~/.bashrc` before starting ranger or open another shell.
For later you want to find out the shell that you are using and edit the proper environment file for it.